# Using the Fill and Replace command to fill up all dispenser?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a schematic of a large build with a couple hundred empty dispensers (facing all different directions) that I wanted replaced with TNT-filled dispensers. I was messing around with the `/fill` command and replace `[oldBlockHandling]` but couldn't get it to work.

```
/fill -884 28 977 -889 25 972 minecraft:dispenser 0 replace {Items:[{id:"tnt",Count:64b,Slot:0b}]}
```

I cut the filling slot to 1 because it won't fit in chat but all this command does is completely fills my selected area with filled dispensers. It doesn't selectively replace empty dispensers, which is what I want. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: "all this command does is completely fills my selected area with filled dispensers" Isn't that exactly what you want? If not, what do you want? And what doesn't work about that command?

Comment: well i wanna replace empty dispenser with full dispensers. so far all im getting is a complete a huge block of dispenser, like the replace part isn't working only the fill is.

Comment: Oh, now I see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The NBT of the to be placed block belongs directly after the to be placed block (technically it's even a part of it). And you didn't tell the game which block to replace. And metadata (the `0`) no longer exists.

```
/fill -884 28 977 -889 25 972 dispenser{Items:[{id:"tnt",Count:64b,Slot:0b}]} replace dispenser
```

Comment: I wrote my 666th answer while it was the first of April in New Zealand and a few other regions. 